# In Django ProgrammingError at /profile/edit/1/ earlier I used sqlite3 database it was fine but when I changed to postgresql it caused this problem

Tags: python, html, django, postgresql, sqlite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tR9H2.png)    ProgrammingError at /profile/edit/1/
relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...

Internal Server Error: /profile/edit/1/

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joych\Downloads\Backup JobB\Job-B\Job-Portal-Django-master\xb\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joych\Downloads\Backup JobB\Job-B\Job-Portal-Django-master\xb\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Joych\Downloads\Backup JobB\Job-B\Job-Portal-Django-master\xb\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Joych\Downloads\Backup JobB\Job-B\Job-Portal-Django-master\xb\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Joych\Downloads\Backup JobB\Job-B\Job-Portal-Django-master\jobapp\permission.py", line 21, in wrap
    return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Joych\Downloads\Backup JobB\Job-B\Job-Portal-Django-master\account\views.py", line 208, in employee_edit_profile
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
  File "C:\Users\Joych\Downloads\Backup JobB\Job-B\Job-Portal-Django-master\xb\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 76, in get_object_or_404
    return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Joych\Downloads\Backup JobB\Job-B\Job-Portal-Django-master\xb\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 431, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Users\Joych\Downloads\Backup JobB\Job-B\Job-Portal-Django-master\xb\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 262, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\Joych\Downloads\Backup JobB\Job-B\Job-Portal-Django-master\xb\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\Joych\Downloads\Backup JobB\Job-B\Job-Portal-Django-master\xb\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\Joych\Downloads\Backup JobB\Job-B\Job-Portal-Django-master\xb\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1169, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Joych\Downloads\Backup JobB\Job-B\Job-Portal-Django-master\xb\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Joych\Downloads\Backup JobB\Job-B\Job-Portal-Django-master\xb\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\Joych\Downloads\Backup JobB\Job-B\Job-Portal-Django-master\xb\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Joych\Downloads\Backup JobB\Job-B\Job-Portal-Django-master\xb\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Joych\Downloads\Backup JobB\Job-B\Job-Portal-Django-master\xb\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Joych\Downloads\Backup JobB\Job-B\Job-Portal-Django-master\xb\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...
```

I dont know why I am getting this error when I am clicking a button to update the information earlier the edit form was opening and working fine when was working on sqlite3 database I have done the migration properly so when I migrated to postgresql this error came other functions in the app are working fine only this edit not working but I have done the migrations properly then also it says

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...

Comment: Did you manually create the PostgreSQL database? Can you use PGAdmin for example, or a command-line to see if the table `auth_user` exists?

Comment: No by python manage.py make migrations and python manage.py migrate and changed my backend sqlite3 to postgresql and changed the local host and then migrated using these two commands python manage.py make migrations and python manage.py migrate

Comment: I have attached an image of  all tables in PGAdmin just see anything missing or not

Comment: `auth_user` is a table that is part of Django's auth system. Did you enable the auth system in the new system per [Auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/)? Also Postgres uses schemas and Django does not really understand them, are you sure the table is not in some other schema then the one your image shows?

Comment: No that is the database current I have migrated database name in postgres is JOBV earlier I used sqlite3 that was working fine but when I changed my database to postgresql it caused the problem but I have migrated properly I think during n=migration I have got this same error that auth_user relation doesnt exist

Comment: If you know how, I would log into PostgresSQL using command line and your credentials (ex: psql) just to make sure your Django project database connections are actually talking to the database that you think it is.

Comment: Okay I am checking it